# [RabbitMQ][Spring] How do I get access to the final exchange name?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, message-listener

For an Exchange-to-Exchange binding definintion

```
public class RabbitRecieveTest implements MessageListener {
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    String firstExchange = message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedExchange();
}
}
```

returns the first exchange name.

Scenario:

Message published to firstExchange <---binding--->secondExchange<---binding---->someQueue<--- listener

I would like to get the name of the secondExchange. Is there a way?

Comment: possibly not, as the message only knows which exchange it is sent to originally.  I do not think that the exchanges themselves add header information.  Having said that unless you have 3 exchanges, you already know which exchange it is coming from in the case of the second exchanges as you have created the binding to it for your queue.  All of this must be done in the consumer side.

Comment: Understood. I have more than 3 exchanges. In the perfect world I would like to know how the message was routed - how did it end-up at the final destination.

Comment: I don't think you can, but not 100%.  Perhaps you could use a custom exchange that adds header info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get this information.